# Scala Regex Extractor with OR operator

Tags: regex, scala, capture-group

I have this verbose code that does shortcircuit Regex extraction / matching in Scala. This attempts to match a string with the first Regex, if that doesn't match, it attempts to match the string with the second Regex.

```
val regex1 : scala.util.matching.Regex = "^a(b)".r
val regex2 : scala.util.matching.Regex = "^c(d)".r

val s = ? 
val extractedGroup1 : Option[String] = s match { case regex1(v) => Some(v) case _ => None }
val extractedGroup2 : Option[String] = s match { case regex2(v) => Some(v) case _ => None}

val extractedValue = extractedGroup1.orElse(extractedGroup2)
```

Here are the results:

> s == "ab" then extractedValue == "b"
>
> s == "cd" then extractedValue == "c"
>
> s == "gg" then extractedValue == None.

My question is how can we combine the two regex into a single regex with the regex or operator, and still use Scala extractors. I tried this, but it's always the None case.

```
val regex : scala.util.matching.Regex = "^a(b)$ | ^c(d)$".r
val extractedValue: s match { case regex(v) => Some(v) case _ => None }
```

Answer (score 0):

Don't use quality of life spaces within the regex, although they feel very scala-esque, they might be taken literary and your program expects that there should be a whitespace after the endOfString or space before the startOfString, which is obviously never the case. Try `^(?:a(b)|c(d))$`, which is the same thing you did without repeating `^` and `$`.

Your own `^a(b)$|^c(d)$` can work too (if you remove the whitespaces).

Also, do you really get `c` out of `cd`? Judging by your regex, you should be getting `d`, if we're talking about capture groups.

Also, note that you're extracting capture groups. If you combine the regexes, an extracted `d` will be $2, while `b` would be $1.

Comment: Also worth noting, the anchors are extraneous since the pattern match extractor regex.matches the entire input. For this simple case, `{ case r1(v) => Some(v) case r2(v) => Some(v)}` is more obvious. Also, use `(?x)` to ignore embedded whitespace.

Comment: You could stick with the original formulation, using `unapplySeq` or: `r1.findFirstMatchIn(s) orElse r2.findFirstMatchIn(s) map (_ group 1)`.